# Convert conditional logic for edge wrapping to math expression

Tags: algorithm, math, glsl, webgl, hlsl

I have a simple function that takes a float parameter `x` in the range `[-1.0, 2.0]` and maps it to range `[0.0, 1.0]` such that values below 0.0 are mapped to 1.0 and values above 1.0 are mapped to 0.0:

```c
float wrap_ternary(x) {
  // result is between [0.0, 1.0]
  return x < 0.0 ? x + 1.0 : x > 1.0 ? x - 1.0 : x;
}
```

I want to convert that function to use math expressions instead of conditionals. I've come up with the following algorithm:

```c
float wrap_mod(x) { 
  return (((x + 1.0) % 2.0 + 1.0) % 1.0);
}
```

However the edge wrapping of this algorithm is inclusive i.e. 1.0/2.0 are mapped to 0.0 whereas the ternary version would map these values to 1.0:

| X | wrap_ternary | wrap_mod | wrong |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |  |
| -0.5 | 0.5 | 0.5 |  |
| 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |  |
| 0.5 | 0.5 | 0.5 |  |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | x |
| 1.5 | 0.5 | 0.5 |  |
| 2.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | x |

How would I modify my algorithm so that it produces the same results as the ternary version? I've tried to subtract EPSILON from my modulo but that didn't really work... I just can't wrap my head around this. No pun intended.

Comment: Might I ask why you don't want to use conditionals? GPUs can execute ternaries quite efficiently; changing this to use modulo and division will not necessarily improve the performance.

Comment: You're probably right but relational operators only work on scalar values and I need to expand this algo to run calculations on vectors. Micro-optimization territory for sure but after banging my head against the wall for over an hour about this I just really want to know how to do the math.

Comment: I do not know glsl, but it seems similar to C. In C, assuming the data operated on is in IEEE-754 single-precision format, you can use `float wrap_floor (float x) { return x - floorf (x * 0.99999994f); }`. The magic constant derives directly from using the epsilon approach you mentioned.

Comment: @njuffa that works beautifully and is even simpler and more optimized than the accepted answer. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it below. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with GLSL, but it seems to be quite similar to C. So below is a C solution `wrap_floor()` that uses the `floor()` function to implement the conditional addition or subtraction, together with a test framework that tests it exhaustively.

The only issue is getting the switchover points correct, which would naturally fall on integers. The question already mentions "epsilon techniques" in which one increases or diminishes floating-point numbers by one ulp (unit in the last place) and which can be used to shift the bounds slightly. To get the correct shift for this case, we need to multiply the input by the "magic" multiplier (1 - 1 ulp). Assuming that `float` maps to the IEEE-754  `binary32` format, the desired number is the literal `float` constant 0.99999994.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// result is between [0.0, 1.0]
float wrap_ternary (float x) {
  return x < 0.0 ? x + 1.0 : x > 1.0 ? x - 1.0 : x;
}

float wrap_floor (float x) { return x - floorf (x * 0.99999994f); }

int main (void)
{
    /* exhaustive test of wrapping functions over [-1,2] */
    float x = -0.0f;
    while (x >= -1.0f) {
        if (wrap_ternary (x) != wrap_floor (x)) {
            printf ("x=% .9e  wrap_ternary = % .8e  wrap_floor=% .8e\n", 
                    x, wrap_ternary (x), wrap_floor (x));
        }
        x = nextafterf (x, -INFINITY);
    }
    x = 0.0f;
    while (x <= 2.0f) {
        if (wrap_ternary (x) != wrap_floor (x)) {
            printf ("x=% .8ef  wrap_ternary = % .8e  wrap_floor=% .8e\n", 
                    x, wrap_ternary (x), wrap_floor (x));
        }
        x = nextafterf (x, INFINITY);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work as expected, though...

```
float wrap_somehow(x) {
    return 0.5 - (frac(1.5 - abs(x - 0.5)) - 0.5) * sign(x - 0.5);
}
```

Comment: It does indeed! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

The `frac` function, which returns the fractional part of a float, seems to have the behaviour you want for all inputs other than `1.0` and `2.0`. So this would work:

```
float wrap_ternary(x) {
  return (x == 1.0 || x == 2.0) ? 1.0 : frac(x);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andrea! That's still a ternary with an OR statement though. I'm specifically looking for a condition-less solution to avoid branching.